# Hibernate HQL query for finding entries older than 3 hours

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

How should I go about setting up HQL condition that would select all the object who's **date** property is older than **3 hours** from **now**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -3);

Query q = session.createQuery("from table where date < :date");
q.setCalendarDate("date", cal);
q.list();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you subtract 3 hours from now and look for `date < :date`?

Comment: I ran into similar problem and in my case DB server time and App Server time is different so this solution is not valid till I am setting the timestamp field with the time of application server.

Comment: Using time from application node to get time difference on db node. That's not a good solution. Use now() db method (based on db engine) and date_sbu with interval if it is needed would be more suitable. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp

Comment: `q.setCalendarDate("date", cal);` is deprecated now. You can use `q.setParameter("date", cal.getTime());`